# Stata: Altering time periods based on running overlap

Tags: stata

I am fairly new to Stata, but working to find the overlap for wide-format time periods in double format.

Once I have the overlap, I want to use it to extend the end of the first time period, and the start of the second period by this overlap.

Here's what I have now:

```
foreach z in 1 2 3... {
     generate overlap = end`z' + 1 - start`z+1' 

     generate end_revised`z' = end`z' + overlap if overlap > 0
     replace end_revised`z' = end`z' if overlap <= 0

     generate start_revised`z+1' = end`z' + overlap + 1 if overlap > 0
     replace start_revised`z+1' = start`z+1' if overlap <= 0

drop overlap
}
```

For some reason, the overlap variable isn't using the start of the next start/end observation set.

Comment: Can you provide some example data and an example of your desired output? What is `end1`, `start2` etc.?

Comment: `double` is a variable or storage type in Stata, not a display format. Although the terms "wide format" and "long format" are in common use for arrangements of data, the term "layout" avoids the overloading of "format", already used for display format, storage type, file format and data layout..

Answer (score 0):

As @Cybernike has flagged, we need more information, especially a data example.

Various comments follow that won't work well as comments.

Your syntax

```
`z + 1'
```

won't work as you guess. You can go say

```
local zp1 = `z' + 1
```

and then refer to that.

Your code can then be rewritten

```
generate overlap = . 
foreach z in 1 2 3 {
     local zp1 = `z' + 1 
     replace overlap = end`z' + 1 - start`zp1' 

     generate end_revised`z' = end`z' + max(0, overlap) 
     generate start_revised`zp1' = cond(overlap > 0, end`z' + overlap + 1,  start`zp1') 
}
```

You evidently have panel data held in wide layout, with a series of start and end times or dates for individuals held in several variables.  You are trying to `generate` yet more variables.....

The general advice on such datasets is that they are much better put through a `reshape long`, but further or indeed better advice would need a data example. Indeed, when starts and ends overlap it is better usually to have a date variable and an event variable, a tactic discussed in [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0068).